# Trying to create a new Postgres connection

Tags: postgresql, docker, dbeaver

I implement a java microservice application deployed under a docker using postgres as data base. I am on MAC. Yesterday I created successfully a connection on DBeaver using the host of my MAC : 192.168.1.73. Today, I cannot connect with this host.

I tried $ telnet 192.168.1.73 5432 and had the following output

```
Trying 192.168.1.73...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.73: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

What can I do ?

### EDIT

I run docker-compose.yml

here is the extract for the data base

```
  database:
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Esprit292948
      - POSTGRES_DB=immo_db_local
```

Here is the begining of docker-compose.yml. I voluntarelly hid the details

```
version: '2'
services:
  eurekaserver:
    image:   ...
    ports:
      - ...
  configserver:
    image: ...
    ports:
      - ...
    environment:
      EUREKASERVER_URI: ...
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: ...
      ENCRYPT_KEY:       ...
  gateservice:
    image: ...
    ports:
      - ...
    environment:
      PROFILE: ...
      SERVER_PORT: ...
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: ...
      EUREKASERVER_URI: ...
      EUREKASERVER_PORT:        ...
      DATABASESERVER_PORT:      "5432"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT:        "8888"
      AUDIT_PORT:               "8087"
      DB_PORT:                  "8930"
  database:
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Esprit292948
      - POSTGRES_DB=immo_db_local
  optimisationfiscaleservice:
    image: ...
    ports:
      - ...
    etc......
```

Here is the ifconfig result

```
$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=50b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether a8:20:66:31:0a:2a 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 20:c9:d0:e0:5d:a1 
    inet6 fe80::41:83de:7236:ba7a%en1 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5 
    inet 192.168.1.73 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:0a:60:f7:bc:80 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr a8:20:66:ff:fe:83:de:f2 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:0a:60:f7:bc:80 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 02:c9:d0:e0:5d:a1 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 0e:b6:7e:12:5d:fb 
    inet6 fe80::cb6:7eff:fe12:5dfb%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::3b2:bb0f:18:dcb7%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::b744:4974:1dd2:5fda%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Comment: Can you explain more, where your java micro-service running? and how you are running it? Is it `docker-compose.yml` or just Docker? Please add the instructions how Postgres is running.

Comment: please check your docker bridge IP for connection or else use docker-compose in which you can provide service name for connection and create network also. also verify your host IP same not changing with time.

Comment: see EDIT. I use docker-compose.yml

Comment: What I don't understand is that it was working yesterday

Comment: Can you add your service as well? Is it running locally on your machine or also in container?

Comment: Hi, postgres runs on docker which runs locally

Answer (score 0):

I didn't pay attention, there was  an error message

```
Name does not resolve
```

So I added "apk add bind-tools" to the docker files to get logs, according to this post : [Docker Compose and Postgres : Name does not resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433522/docker-compose-and-postgres-name-does-not-resolve)

After which I had another error

```
Docker error : no space left on device
```

So according to this post [Docker error : no space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device) : I run

```
docker system prune
```

And then, I succedded to connect with DBeaver